# DevExpress CheckedComboBoxEdit

Tags: vb.net, devexpress

Приложение на VB.net.  Есть элемент CheckedComboBoxEdit, который заполняеться так:

```
        storedPar = SqlHelperParameterCache.GetSpParameterSet(BasicCover.strSQL, "sql procedure")
        storedPar(0).Value = 0

        dsFiliales = SqlHelper.ExecuteDataset(BasicCover.strSQL, CommandType.StoredProcedure,
        "sql procedure", storedPar)
        Dim tb As DataTable = dsFiliales.Tables(0)

        RepositoryItemCheckedComboBoxEditFiliales.DataSource = dsFiliales.Tables(0)
        RepositoryItemCheckedComboBoxEditFiliales.ValueMember = 
        RepositoryItemCheckedComboBoxEditFiliales.DisplayMember =
```

Проблема заключается в том что при самом первом выборе элемента код ниже не срабатывает

```
    Dim dt As DataTable = New DataTable("TAB") : dt.Columns.Add("ID", GetType(Int64))
    For Each it As DevExpress.XtraEditors.Controls.CheckedListBoxItem In RepositoryItemCheckedComboBoxEditFiliales.GetItems()
        If it.CheckState = CheckState.Checked Then
            'RegNumbList.Add(GridView1.GetRowCellValue(rowHandle, "IDLift").ToString())
            dt.Rows.Add(New Object() {it.Value})
        End If
    Next
```

т.е. как будто не элемента Checked. В повтором выборе элементов Checked все работает корректно.

Comment: Этот код в обработчике какого события написан?

Comment: EditValueChanged

Comment: `EditValueChanged` означает, что закончилось редактирование значения. А фиксация _выбора_ (check) ещё может быть не завершена. Вам, вероятно, следует обрабатывать событие `CheckedChanged` или что-то наподобие (не знаю, какие именно события в контролах DevExpress).

Comment: спасибо за совет попробую изменить

Answer (score 0):

В событии EditValueChanged синхронизация между EditValue и коллекцией RepositoryItemCheckedComboBoxEdit.Items не гарантирована. Например, если EditValue изменить без участия со стороны пользователя, синхронизация произойдет только после того, как отработают все подписчики события EditValueChanged.

Как правило, событие EditValueChanged используется для обработки нового EditValue. У CheckedComboBoxEdit тип EditValue задается свойством [RepositoryItemCheckedComboBoxEdit.EditValueType](https://docs.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/DevExpress.XtraEditors.Repository.RepositoryItemCheckedComboBoxEdit.EditValueType).

CSV - это строка, которая содержит выбранные элементы через разделитель. Разделитель задается свойством [RepositoryItemCheckedComboBoxEdit.SeparatorChar](https://docs.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/DevExpress.XtraEditors.Repository.RepositoryItemCheckedComboBoxEdit.SeparatorChar).

```vb
Private Sub RepositoryItemCheckedComboBoxEdit_EditValueChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
    Dim editor As BaseEdit = DirectCast(sender, BaseEdit)
    Dim value As String = CStr(editor.EditValue)
    Dim selectedValues() As Integer = value.Split(editor.Properties.SeparatorChar) _
        .Select(Function(t) Integer.Parse(t)) _
        .ToArray()
End Sub
```

List - это объект типа List.

```vb
Private Sub RepositoryItemCheckedComboBoxEdit_EditValueChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
    Dim editor As BaseEdit = DirectCast(sender, BaseEdit)
    Dim selectedValues As List(Of Object) = CType(editor.EditValue, List(Of Object))
End Sub
```